# IndexError: List Index out of range Keras Tokenizer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm working with the sentiment140 dataset to try and learn sentiment analysis using RNNs. I found this tutorial online that uses the `keras.imdb` datasource, but I want to try and use my own datasource, so I have tried to adapt the code my own data. 
Tutorial: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-on-sentiment-analysis-with-rnn-9e100627c02e

The data preprocessing involves extracting series data and then tokenizing and padding it before sending it to the model for training. I performed these operations below, in my code but whenever I try to run the training I get `if isinstance(data[0], list):IndexError: list index out of range`. I did not define `data` so this leads me to believe that I did something that keras or tensorflow did not like. Any ideas as to what is causing this error?

My data is currently in a csv file format with the headers being `SENTIMENT` and `TEXT`. `SENTIMENT` is `0` for negative and `1` for positive. `TEXT` is the processed tweet that was collected. Here is a sample.

Dataset CSV (Only a view lines to save space)

```
SENTIMENT,TEXT
0,about to file tax
0,ahh i hate dogs
1,My paycheck came in today
1,lot to do before chi this weekend
1,lol love food
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import keras
import keras.preprocessing.text as kpt
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import json
import numpy as np


# Load in DS
df = pd.read_csv('./train.csv')
print(df.head())

#Create sequence
vocabulary_size = 1000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words= vocabulary_size, split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['TEXT'].values)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['TEXT'].values)

#Pad Sequence
X_train = pad_sequences(X_train)
print(X_train)

#Get Sentiment
y_train = df['SENTIMENT'].tolist()


#create model
max_words = 24
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Dropout
embedding_size=32
model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_size, input_length=max_words))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
             optimizer='adam', 
             metrics=['accuracy'])

batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 3
X_valid, y_valid = X_train[:batch_size], y_train[:batch_size]
X_train2, y_train2 = X_train[batch_size:], y_train[batch_size:]
model.fit(X_train2, y_train2,
    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs)
```

Output

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
   SENTIMENT                                               TEXT
0          0  aww that be bummer You shoulda get david carr ...
1          0  be upset that he can not update his facebook b...
2          0  I dive many time for the ball manage to save t...
3          0      my whole body feel itchy and like its on fire
4          0  no it be not behave at all be mad why be here ...
[[  0   0   0 ...   3  10   5]
 [  0   0   0 ...  46  47  89]
 [  0   0   0 ...  29   9  96]
 ...
 [  0   0   0 ...  30 309 310]
 [  0   0   0 ...   0   0  72]
 [  0   0   0 ...  33 312 313]]
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 24, 32)            32000
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               53200
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101
=================================================================
Total params: 85,301
Trainable params: 85,301
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mcve.py", line 50, in <module>
    epochs=num_epochs)
  File "/home/dv/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 950, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/dv/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 787, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/dv/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 79, in standardize_input_data
    if isinstance(data[0], list):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

JUPYTER NOTEBOOK ERROR

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-184505b70981> in <module>()
     20 model.fit(X_train2, y_train2,
     21     batch_size=batch_size,
---> 22     epochs=num_epochs)
     23 

~/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    948             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    949             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 950             batch_size=batch_size)
    951         # Prepare validation data.
    952         do_validation = False

~/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    785                 feed_output_shapes,
    786                 check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 787                 exception_prefix='target')
    788 
    789             # Generate sample-wise weight values given the `sample_weight` and

~/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
     77                              'for each key in: ' + str(names))
     78     elif isinstance(data, list):
---> 79         if isinstance(data[0], list):
     80             data = [np.asarray(d) for d in data]
     81         elif len(names) == 1 and isinstance(data[0], (float, int)):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**
My former suggestion is wrong. I've checked your code and run it, and it works without errors for me. 
Then I've looked at the source code, [`standardize_input_data`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f130fa1bca288cb566b083620ba70cb89e2e5fdd/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L32) function. There's a line which checks a `data` argument:

```
def standardize_input_data(data,
                           names,
                           shapes=None,
                           check_batch_axis=True,
                           exception_prefix=''):
    """Normalizes inputs and targets provided by users.
    Users may pass data as a list of arrays, dictionary of arrays,
    or as a single array. We normalize this to an ordered list of
    arrays (same order as `names`), while checking that the provided
    arrays have shapes that match the network's expectations.
    # Arguments
        data: User-provided input data (polymorphic).
        ...
```

At the line 79:

```
 elif isinstance(data, list):
        if isinstance(data[0], list):
            ...
```

So, it looks like in case of error an input data is `list`, but a list of zero length.

A `standartize_input_data` function is called inside Model.fit(...) method throught a call to Model._standardize_user_data(...). Through this chain of functions, passed `data` argument gets a value of `x` argument of `Model.fit(x, y, ...)`. So, I guess is that the problem with type or content of `X_train2` or `X_valid`.  Would you provide `X_train2` and `X_val` in addition to `X_train` content?

**Old wrong suggestion**
You should increase vocabulary size by one to deal with out-of-vocabulary tokens, I guess.
I.e, change initialization of the `Embedding` layer:

```
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size + 1, embedding_size, input_length=max_words))
```

According to the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/), *"input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1".*
You may check a max. value of the `max(X_train)` (*edited*).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't think of that. I think my problem however has something to do with data tokenization. I ran the code in a jupyter notebook and added it's output above as well. Maybe that can help

Comment: Running `max(df['TEXT'].values)` returns this string `yes what do you want to do` which is the longest string in the set.

Comment: @ex080 I'll look at it more closely tomorrow

Comment: @ex080 I just have improved my answer, need some additional data

Comment: I'll provide the data as soon as I get home today.

Comment: Ok, so I took your suggestion and it worked. Turned out that pandas was the fault it was importing the dataframe and assigning types which caused data to be empty. was fixed by `df.TEXT=df.TEXT.astype(str)`